# RecyclerView Implementation MVC

Tags: java, android, android-studio, model-view-controller, android-recyclerview

I started learning MVC architecture but I can't figure out how to implement RecyclerView correctly,especially OnClick.

I tried looking for it online but the tutorials are different and I couldn't find a proper way to implement it and understand it.

Can someone show me how to do this in the **correct** and simplest way ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please refer here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-model-view-controller-architecture-pattern-in-android-with-example/

Comment: Thanks, I saw the tutorial but is that how you implement it ? shouldn't be a Controller class ? shouldn't all the views logic have to be separate from the main activity ?
I am confused a little...
And there is no recyclerview in that tutorial..